# Ubercart Numerical Attributes Not Respecting List Position Settings

Tags: 7, ubercart

I have an attribute option select box field that has numerical options, like this:

```
LENGTH
1
1.5
2
10
100
```

However, this is how the options are displaying on the front-end view of the product:

```
LENGTH
1
1.5
10
100
2
```

As you can see, it is sorting anything that starts with a "1" before anything that starts with a "2". I need it to be in literal numerical format.

Any ideas on how I can make this work the way I need it to?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) manages options twice. First in the overall (global) attributes, which may be applied to any individual product, then in the realm of the individual product. Since the product may have only a subset of the global options selection, once you have applied an attribute to a product, you are able to select which options apply, and re-order the sort order for that product. The default sort in Drupal is alphabetical.

Edit your product, go to the options tab, and set the options order the way you want to see it. The select list will respect the order you set. (And yes, this will require you to repeat the process for every product.)

EDIT:

One possible way to brute force the ordering is with direct access to the database.

First go to /admin/store/products/attributes and open the options list(s) for your attribute(s). Drag and drop to get the options in the correct order, then save.

Then run the following query (after backing up your database in case it blows up):

```
UPDATE uc_product_options p JOIN uc_attribute_options a ON p.oid=a.oid SET p.ordering = a.ordering;
```

Just be aware that if you ever edit the attributes on a product, they will re-order with the selected options at the top, and the unselected options at the end of the list. You WILL have to double check the order before saving, as the selected attributes will probably be in alphabetical order.

Comment: I'm actually trying to avoid that. The Length attribute has over 500 options, and that attribute is listed on almost 200 products. Needless to say, it would take an immense amount of time (and patience!) to update that attribute's order on every single product. Do you know of any way to "brute-force" the order via the database or something along those lines (or by removing Ubercart's automatic alphabetization)?

Comment: Been there. Done that (3000+ products). Required hand editing because each product had only a few of the massive list of options. The list reordered itself when the selected options moved to the top. It was a simple matter to drag and drop the desired sequence and to define a default, then save. But it did take a long time :-) If you have direct access to the database there might be a way to brute force it (Adding edt to answer.)

Comment: When I view the options for a product (and also when I view the options in the /admin/store/products/attributes admin section), it shows my first 50 options with list positions 1-50 for the length attribute. Then, every option after that in the length attribute has a list position of "-50". I wonder if the issue is that the list position selector only goes up to 50. What if I increased that value to "1000"... do you think that would fix my issue? If so, any ideas on how I would make that adjustment?